# In the suburbs vs. On the ouskirts

Tags: prepositions

In the following examples, we have used the prepositions "in" before "suburbs" and "on" before " outskirts". Is there any explation for this usage?

I live in the suburbs of London.
I live on the outskirts of London.

Comment: @deadrat: l think it is not a duplicate.My question includes "in the suburbs".

Comment: Retracted for that reason.